How do i get the exact surface area of a complex model
I have a complex bridge model made of around 3000 objects but a lot of them are inside eachother adding to the surface area so i want them away.
i tried using bool tool but some faces disappear.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

May I know why you need the aurface area? Do you just need to get an estimate? You could join all objects together and then Remesh (Voxel) it and use this method to calculate surface area.

There is no functionality for that. You have to join them somehow. Booleans are a viable option, they just don't always work, so you could try combining few parts at a time until that works, making sure to move the parts slightly(fractions that do not interfere with your purpose, maybe millimeters if you are working in tens of meters) if you run into problems. You can also try different Boolean algorithms (fast/exact). Booleans generally might not work well if you have vertices that are very close together or overlapping geometry, n-gons, non-manifold geometry or sometimes no apparent reason at all. Boolean algorithms are not perfect in pretty much any surface modelling software.
